# Registered and NotRegistered Contacts not showing in my Flutter chat app unless I do Hot Start

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-cubit

I'm learning Flutter now and i'm creating chat app using Firebase as a backend and BloC Cubit as a state management and i have some issues in my project.

I'm using Fast Contacts Package for displaying contacts in the app.

```
List<Contact> contacts =[];

Future getAllContacts() async{
bool isGranted = await Permission.contacts.request().isGranted;
if(!isGranted){
  isGranted = await Permission.contacts.request().isGranted;
}
await FastContacts.getAllContacts(
).then((value){
  contacts = value;
  emit(GetContactsState());
}).catchError((error){
});
}
```

And i have a function to get all users phone numbers in Firebase Firestore to compare it with the contacts in my phone to know the registered contacts in Firebase and storing the registered users in a registered list and not registered users in notRegistered list and showing the two lists in the same screen.

```
 getAllUsers() async{
emit(GetAllUsersLoadingState());
String phoneNum ='';
bool numFound = false;
try {
  var users = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(userCollection).get();

  for(var num in contacts){
    numFound = false;
    phoneNum = num.phones[0].number.replaceAll(' ', '');
    for (var document in users.docs) {
      var userData = UserModel.fromJson(document.data());
      if (phoneNum == userData.phone && userData.id != currentUser!.uid) {
        registerUsers.add(phoneNum);
        numFound = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!numFound) notRegistered.add(phoneNum);
  }    

  emit(GetAllUsersSuccessState());
} catch(error) {
  emit(GetAllUsersFailureState());
}
}
```

But the problem is the the two lists not displaying anything unless i restart app.

main.dart::::

```
void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await Firebase.initializeApp();


 runApp(
  MyApp(
));
 }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider(create: (context) => 
   ChatCubit()..getAllContacts()..getAllUsers()),

    ],
    child: const MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: PageOne()
    ),
);
 }
}
```

contacts_page.dart

```
class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
 const ContactsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
 State<ContactsPage> createState() => _ContactsPageState();
}

class _ContactsPageState extends State<ContactsPage> {

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocBuilder<ChatCubit, ChatState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    var cubit = ChatCubit.get(context);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('contacts'),),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Text('Registered Contacts',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: cubit.registerUsers.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                       
                          },
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                            child: Text(
                                cubit.registerUsers[index]
                            ),
                          )
                      );
                    }
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                Text('Contacts Not '
                    'Registered',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),

                ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

                    itemCount: cubit.notRegistered.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Text(index.toString() + cubit.notRegistered[index],
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),);
                    }
                ),
              ],
            )

          ],
        )

    );
  },
);


 }


 }
```